# Как преобразовать Image к BufferedImage

Tags: java, javafx

Как преобразовать `Image` к `BufferedImage`?

```java
Image image = imgView.getImage();
BufferedImage source = (BufferedImage) image;
```

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал это так

```
Image image = imgView.getImage();
BufferedImage source = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null);
```